# Implementing SAML Single Logout on Weblogic - How to get SessionIndex from Weblogic / IdP?

Tags: java, weblogic, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I need to implement SAML 2.0 Single logout using WSO2 Identity Server as the identity provider and Weblogic 11g as service provider.

According to SAML specification, there are two different roles service providers participating in the single logout process can take: the service provider who started it, who sends an LogoutRequest to the identity provider, and the service providers who get a LogoutRequest from the identity server and respond accordingly with a LogoutResponse and close their respective sessions. When those service providers have finished the identity provider then responds accordingly to the first service provider who started it all with a LogoutResponse of its own. http://winfinit.tumblr.com/post/84924299219/saml2-single-logout-slo-with-wso2-is-4-5

In this scenario I need to implement the first role, when my custom servlet generates the LogoutRequest and sends it to the identity server: since Weblogic 11g surprisingly doesn't support SAML2 Single Logout a servlet will generate and respond according to the SAML specification and close the session using the ServletAuthentication.logout() method in the Weblogic API.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> 
<saml2p:LogoutRequest 
    xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
    ID="jofpphihclkakoifhaeenbdeakfidojehgnpobpg" 
    IssueInstant="2014-05-05T20:00:13.653Z" 
    NotOnOrAfter="2014-05-05T20:05:13.653Z" 
    Reason="Single Logout" 
    Version="2.0">
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">web3001</saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2:NameID xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">admin</saml2:NameID> 
    <saml2p:SessionIndex>8c97787b-48f5-425d-8f88-39befe58eaad</saml2p:SessionIndex>
</saml2p:LogoutRequest>
```

Which is the best way for getting the values for filling in the last two attributes, namely saml2:NameID and saml2p:SessionIndex?

Comment: Weblogic 12.2 still does not support SAML 2.0 SLO
[Weblogic 12.2 Administering Security](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/SECMG/saml20.htm#SECMG478) "...because SAML logout is not supported in WebLogic Server..."

It may never will.